# Enum with enumMember attribute create more object than enum without this attribute why?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, .net-framework-version

I've WCF application and I made simple test sending lot of request to just one endpoint.
In memory profiler I saw that enum type where is added EnumMember attribute was created thousand obejct, but other enum without this attribute was just one.
I was looking good explained on google but still I don't know why it happened and what is the difference between below enum:

```
public enum Status 
{
   NotActive = 1,
   Active = 2
}
```

and

```
public enum Status 
{
   [EnumMember]
   NotActive = 1,
   [EnumMember]
   Active = 2
}
```

I want to change this implementation to remove this attribute but I am not sure why some add this attribute but not each enum type.
I will be grateful if somebody could in simple words explain this or give me any article on google.

Comment: **[EnumMember]** : It is often used to modify property values. Such as [EnumMember(Value = "In Progress")]
     NotActive = 1. It will change from<Status> NotActive = 1</Status> to<Status> In Progress</Status>

Answer (score 1):

I tested it further and I think the reason could be this:

First, **EnumMember** allows **enum** types to be serialized and deserialized in **WCF**.

If your enum types don't have the **EnumMember** attribute added to them, they won't be serialized in **WCF** and will show the **GetStatusRequestBody** data.
[image]
The enum data will only be serialized if **EnumMember** feature is added.
[image]

So I think that's probably the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what the problem is, I don't know if there is a printscreen of where the enum was instantiated and the memory profiler showing that a thousand objects were created, but the EnumMember annotation serves to assist in deserialization and customize enum values, if you don't want to customizing anything, there would be no need.

- test via api/swagger the passing of values to this enum and validate if it is what you expect,
- also check the microsoft doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute?view=net-8.0

Comment: I'll make screen from my test to demonstrate created object.